# How to stop camera from moving further than the map?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, transform

So i have a 2D world in Unity which has a sprite (Some hills). That is the map. I also have a camera that moves left - right when the mouse reaches the borders of the game's window using the following script (I hope it's not too messy, i'm lazy today :/ , i will add some comments to help).

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera Camera; //idk why i did this the component is parented to maincam
    public float Divider; //This is to reduce the move amount to reasonable numbers.
    void Start()
    {
         
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition; //The simple stuff. Getting the mouse position

        Debug.Log(mousePos.x); //Some debug stuff
        Debug.Log(mousePos.y);
        Debug.Log(Screen.width / 14);
        Debug.Log(Screen.width - (Screen.width / 14));
        
        if (mousePos.x < Screen.width / 14) //The if statement to trigger the movement only when the mouse is in the calculated border radius. I use the example   49 < 700 / 14 = 49 < 50
        {
            Camera.transform.Translate((mousePos.x - Screen.width / 14) / Divider, 0, 0); //Move the camera to the left by the calculated strength which is the distance between the mouse and the border radius end reduced to reasonable amounts by the Divider variable. It is set to 50 in the engine currently. The example is   (49 - 700 / 14) / 50 = (49 - 50) / 50 = -1 / 50 = -0.02
            Debug.Log((mousePos.x - Screen.width / 14) / Divider); //Debug stuff
        } else if (mousePos.x > Screen.width - (Screen.width / 14)) //If not, we'll check if the mouse is in the right. We calculate the right border radius by subtracting the full width of the game window by the calculated radius.   651 > 700 - (700 / 14) = 651 > 700 - 50 = 651 > 650
        {
            Camera.transform.Translate((mousePos.x - (Screen.width - (Screen.width / 14))) / Divider, 0, 0); //The same, but we replace the left with right using the algorithm that's explained above.
            Debug.Log((mousePos.x - (Screen.width - (Screen.width / 14))) / Divider); //DEBUGGGG
        }
    }
}
```

So that's the code. Now i want to add the logic for stopping the camera from extending further than the map. The problem is that i want the game to be responsive, so the set limitations are not an option. I had an idea that could possibly work exactly how i wanted, but it didn't work for some reason. When searching on the internet i found a solution, but it was confusing and unexplained, so i decided to make this post, I will be really thankful if you help!
[This is an image of the scene if needed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrbzv.png)

Comment: `stopping the camera from extending further than the map` .. what is `the map`? `I had an idea that could possibly work exactly how i wanted, but it didn't work for some reason` .. what idea? and what exactly didn't work?

Comment: The map is a wide static sprite that the camera can scroll. I don't know how to explain clearer, i will give an image. Since you can't embed images in comments, i just searched for a free image hosting website. Here's the link: https://ibb.co/7XJpM1V
Oops wrong image here's the image i meant to send

Also, about the idea, i realised it's dumb, i don't want to talk about it

Comment: You can just use cinemachine package since that has built in features for this. It will also ease out most of your camera related problems aswell.

Comment: What? It has? Wow, thanks! Any ideas on how it works and where to turn it on?

Comment: Check out some videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izumXk-xoEM&ab_channel=samyam) one. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.3/manual/CinemachineConfiner.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Sorry @ÇağatayIŞIK , but I don't think Cinemachine is a good option. All it does for me is stops the camera from moving completely. I did everything like in the tutorial. Then i tried to find the problem myself. I found out that the Virtual camera stops the Main camera from changing anything completely. I found a field called Follow and tried attaching it to the camera, it worked at first, but it definetly not confining it. I even may call it skipping the confinement borders. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can continue to come up with your own solution but i am suprised that cinemachine did not work for you. Maybe you have used it wrongly i am not sure. Cinemachine is a big and widely used package so if you try to learn it more i am sure you can fix it.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK I do not know why it didn't work. It just makes the camera immovable. I have a story of me having a bad relationship with Cinemachine. Every time i use it, it refuses to work. Are you sure you don't have any other way to implement the system? I really need to implement this, and i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint()` and `spriteRenderer.bounds`.